# Easiest way to get a list of tags for which I've bee the first user? Algorithmically if possible!

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I have created >several tags without sufficient documentation. As far as I know there's no easy way for me to get a list of tags by creator (a mod here may have told me that, I can't remember where or when) but a list of tags for which a question that I've asked is the first use would be just fine for me to get to work on this.

Is there a way to script this? I've seen some kind of scripting being mentioned here from time to time, though I've never used it. Now I can't even remember what it's called. It's been around a while.

I have squirreled away the following two links which seem to suggest there's another way to do this without "going deep" into developerland and using a python API. Would this (below) be an easier way than scripting?

https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/15/you-can-now-play-with-stack-overflow-data-on-googles-bigquery/?cb=1

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow

If someone could post the text of an actual script or query that does this, that would be super!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/space/revision/680428/848355/) is a query for you

I am terrible at writing those things, so this is a bunch of stuff I copy pasted from other queries. Surprisingly it works.

Input your userID to get a list of what tags you created (yours is 12102)

Comment: WOW! Eighty Tags? OK. Thank you very much for your help, that worked great. This will keep me busy for a while. :)

Comment: I'm thinking of simplifying this script, but I'm actually clueless. I don't know what language it's written in nor where one could find the documentation. Any thoughts?

Comment: @uhoh the [Stack Exchange data explorer tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) is a good place to start

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a go when I'm in need of my next fix of "SE-based procrastination".