# Do we have or do we need a tag for robotic aircraft used to explore other planets?

Tags: discussion

Do we have or do we need a tag for robotic aircraft used to explore other planets?

I noticed this lack when I posted the new question [Why Never-EVER Land?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26154/12102)

It looks like we have no appropriate tag, and yet there are many questions about this.

What would be an appropriate tag and definition for this kind of question?

Comment: Technically, according to the tag description, the [tag:rovers] tag would appy to robotic aircraft: "Questions about vehicles sent to extraterrestrial bodies, generally for use in data collection."

Comment: @called2voyage hmm... that might have been before the "cosmic (tag) inflation era", back when people were rightfully conservative and cautious and trying to avoid tag inflation. So out of more than just *curiosity*, I will take this *opportunity* to honor that *spirit* and use the `rovers` tag, at least until *2020*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dang it, I started to create an extraterrestrial aircraft tag, then I noticed we already have the tag you are asking for--and you've used it before!

[aerobot](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aerobot)

Of course, extraterrestrial aircraft is a slightly broader category, and if there is a need for it we could still add that tag, but for now I think aerobot will do.

Comment: Great find, thank you! I'll look into it today and tidy up. On my proverbial list of things to do is to track down all the tags I've *generated without taking the time to define* (there are over 100 I believe, see this [question](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/881/12102) for background and its answer) and posting a *mea culpa*-class community wiki with tentative definitions for community review. I wonder if there might be an even better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it would be worthwhile. Flying robots are a different category in many ways then other types of landers, and should be judged accordingly.

Comment: I think if we had such a tag it should be "extraterrestrial-aircraft". NASA sometimes uses "Planetary Flight Vehicles", but in an [article](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/news/X-Press/stories/2005/xtra_072005_PlanetaryFlightVehicle.html) by that name the word "aircraft" is used repeatedly. "Extraterrestrial aircraft" is the Wikipedia category for such things.

Comment: It should include Balloons, which are proposed for both Titan and Venus, and possibly others that I am not aware of...