# Are questions about the U.S. Space Force on topic? Tag needed?

Tags: discussion, tags

There have been questions and answers which have mentioned the U.S. Space Force.

1. Do we want questions specifically about it on-topic?
2. If so, should there be a tag?
3. How should such a tag be spelled out?
4. Should the tag also apply to other countries' (possibly future) space forces?
5. How do these issues interact with the exiting [military](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military) tag?

I have 3 or 4 potential questions.

Comment: There was a tag, but it seems it's disappeared from lack of use.

Comment: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/how-is-our-tagging-situation-what-can-we-do-to-improve-it#comment5886_1602

Comment: Wow @called2voyage, you are fast!

Comment: You caught me online! :)

Comment: @called2voyage a false choice! You can be (and are usually) *both* fast *and* online :-)